# Terminal Frozen

Tags: 14.04

I ran a fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop and tried to install Sentora Panel, everything went well until AppArmor was disabled by the installer package. I was prompted with the line

`Restart your server now to complete the install (y/n)?`

with a blank box trailing at the end preventing me from answering the question. I tried installing before, and being prevented from restarting, i force shutdown my computer, Ubuntu then would not restart and I had to entirely re-install Ubuntu as it would not launch.

Any idea how to fix this or what causes it?

Comment: What happens when you start? Did Ubuntu disable the power button?

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/617574/edit) your question and add the following: Which version of Sentora panel? Have you downloaded an archive or have you used the Git version? More infos please. Then give me a comment with @A.B.